# What is the purpose of the error inside method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

i started to study Objective-C with book recommended here (programming in objective-c) and i have 2 questions:

for example in the method who copy file:

```
NSString *path, newPath;
NSFilemanager;

if([fm copyItemToPath: path toPath newPath error: NULL] == NO)
{
    MSLOG(@"The file does not exist");
}
```

1. what is the purpose the error section inside the if and why in the example who taken from book it's null
2. i did not understand the meaning of the NO at the and of the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NO` is the return value of the `copyItemToPath` method.  It returns `NO` (which is the same as `false`) if the file copy operation was not successful.

The `NULL` for the error means the returned error isn't important in this case and can be ignored.  Otherwise you pass a pointer to an `NSError` object:

```
NSError *error;
if([fm copyItemToPath: path toPath newPath error: &error] == NO) {
  NSLog(@"Error is %@", [error.localizedDescription]);

....
```

The error message returns the reason why the return value of the function is `false`.

Comment: why after successfully copy  my file i still get null in my error ? i mean it just print  Error is (null)

Comment: The `NSError` is only returned if there was an error in processing the method call, otherwise it's returned as `nil`.

Comment: It's actually not guaranteed that the error will be set to anything in particular when the call succeeds. It's best not to look at it unless an error occurred, as it could just be garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to clean up the code: both declarations of `NSString` are pointers, you need to declare a variable pointer for `NSFileManager`, your method is missing a `:`, and the `if` text should be `NSLog`

So we have :

```
NSString *path, *newPath;
NSFilemanager *fm;

if([fm copyItemToPath: path toPath: newPath error: NULL] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"The file does not exist");
}
```

The `NULL` for `err` is the default action, which for `BOOL` is `YES` if the code succeeds or `NO` if it fails.

The `==NO` is a fail-safe for the return value. since sometimes it is `1` or `0` or `true` or `false`, which may cause errors.

Comment: why after successfully copy my file i still get null in my error ? i mean it just print Error is (null)

Comment: Because NULL means the operation was successful which means YES.  Unless you mean it also logs "The file does not exist" - is it printing this String out?

Comment: NULL does not mean the operation was successful.

Comment: @bbum - Sorry you're right, NULL is the default error unless, as Richard Brown said above, you create your own error method... right?

Comment: Passing NULL for the `error` out-parameter just tells the API not to bother calculating specific error details.  Whether or not there was an error is determined entirely by the return value of the method.